# Margin surrounding flex container

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have here a flex display which divides the screen into two areas wherein one half has some login info and the other has a background picture. When trying to set the flex, however, i am met with these margins on both sides (orange bars as indicated in inspect element). How do I get rid of these?

[image]

Attached is the return value to display and css

```
        <div className="container">
            <div className="login-col">
            <h2>User Login</h2>
            <MDBContainer fluid className="p-10 my-5">
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol col='4' md='6'>

                    <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Email address' id='email' type='email' size="lg"/>
                    <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Password' id='password' type='password' size="lg"/>

                    <MDBBtn className="mb-4 w-100" size="lg" onClick={login}>Sign in</MDBBtn>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>
            </div>  
        <div className="img-col">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and its css

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: max-content;
}

.login-col{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.img-col{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('img.jpg'); 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image-panel img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container's width is 100vh, meaning 100% viewport HEIGHT. Change it to `width: 100vw` (viewport width)

Comment: Hi, ive set it to vw only really noticed it now. margin at the sides still persist though.

Comment: @honj-t Please check via Inspector, which element the margin belongs to. Or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: From what I've checked in inspector, it belongs to .container though I did try setting margin to auto and 0 but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I had conflicting css related to className `container`. Renaming it to something unique fixed the issue.